# Getting the 'Tab' Index in Sitecore

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore

I am using Sitecore and I have a webpage which contains a tab. This tab can have 1 or many children. Now there is a promotions control which dynamically change as according to which tab is selected.

So if I selected Tab1, then some promotion will be shown at that page. Tab2 might have different/same promo. These two are placed in different controls.

All I got is this code so far:

```
        Sitecore.Data.Database db = Sitecore.Context.Database;
        Item home = db.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath);
        var getItems = (from Item item in currItem.Children.InnerChildren 
                        select item).ToList();
```

Result of this query is 3 items. Because there are 3 tabs. These tabs are in repeater like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptPromo" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptPromo_ItemBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <table width="100%">
          <tbody>
                 <tr>

                     <td>
                         <h2><sup><sc:Text ID="txtPromo" Field="PromoText" runat="server" /></sup></h2>
                    </td>

                 </tr>

           </tbody>
    </table>    
</ItemTemplate>
```

How to get the info of which tab is selected. I am changing the PROMO control in a separate function:

```
 protected void rptPromo_ItemBound (Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        Item i = e.Item.DataItem as Item;
        Text txtPromo = e.Item.FindControl("txtPromo") as Text;
        //txtPromo.Attributes.Add("txtPromo", txtPromo);
        //HTMLControl hyperLinkLookUp = e.Item.FindControl("") as 
        string s;
    }
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The Text control needs to know the Item context. If one is not set, it assumes the current Context Item that you're on which would result in 3 duplicate PromoTexts appearing in the repeater (or none at all if the PromoText field does not occur on the current context item).

You already have the `Field` property defined on the Text control, so all you need to do is to assign its `Item` property as follows:

```
protected void rptPromo_ItemBound (Object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Item i = e.Item.DataItem as Item;
    Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Text txtPromo = e.Item.FindControl("txtPromo") as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Text;
    txtPromo.Item = i;

    //txtPromo.Attributes.Add("txtPromo", txtPromo);
    //HTMLControl hyperLinkLookUp = e.Item.FindControl("") as 
    string s;
}
```

Comment: Where at? This does not answers my question!

Comment: I've updated my answer. Perhaps you should restate your question. It's a little unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: txtPromo does not have a property called 'Item'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it does. The `sc:Text` control exists under Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Text You may be inheriting from some other class. Try `Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Text txtPromo = e.Item.FindControl("txtPromo") as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Text;`